# How to interpret ALL_TAB_COLS.DATA_LENGTH = 4000 for Oracle's CLOB types?

Tags: sql, oracle, types, clob

When I create a table with a `CLOB` in it, the `CLOB` column is reported to have a `DATA_LENGTH` of 4000:

```
create table test (
  data clob
);

-- Returns 4000
select data_length from all_tab_cols
where table_name = 'TEST';
```

How can I interpret that? Is that some backwards-compatible tweak, considering that the limit for `VARCHAR2` is also 4000? Or is this to indicate that I can only insert / update string literals of length 4000? Is this behaviour of [`SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2090.htm) documented somewhere?

Comment: See this answer for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7211606/409172

Comment: @jonearles: Thanks for the hint. That makes things even more confusing. I guess, for merely logical (i.e. non-storage-related) purposes, I can ignore the `DATA_LENGTH` of a `CLOB` column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to 4000 bytes can be stored in-line in the tablespace. If the length of the CLOB exceeds 4000 bytes it must be stored in/readed from LOB storage area via special functions.

See also:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_blob.htm
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_table_blob_lob_storage.htm

Comment: That might explain it as well, yes. But in principle, `ALL_TAB_COLS.DATA_LENGTH` could still be `NULL` or the `CLOB` upper limit, as `4000` is not a real (logical) limit to `CLOB` columns

Comment: If You disable storage in row: TABLESPACE "USERS" DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW value will be less (86 in my case)