# How to define Oracle BLOB length

Tags: oracle, blob, data-dictionary

I encount a `BLOB` column in my project,and the `DATA_LENGTH` column was 4000!

And how to define a `BLOB` length?

Can Oracle `BLOB` could define length?

I find to Oracle reference and Internet and get nothing.

Comment: BLOB are intended to store large objects. Can go into gigabytes. Usually, you don't place constraints on them. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687375/oracle-10g-can-clob-data-lengths-be-less-than-4-000 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137992/how-to-interpret-all-tab-cols-data-length-4000-for-oracles-clob-types?lq=1

Comment: @Thilo Because i find the BLOB type length was 4000 and i don't understand!!

Comment: See this other SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7211606/146325

Comment: possible duplicate of [BLOB storage length in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553549/blob-storage-length-in-oracle)