# BLOB storage length in oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, blob, ddl

I am trying to migrate a table from DB2 to Oracle.

The `CREATE DDL` query contains a column with datatype as `BLOB(102400)` in DB2.

But when I specify the  same data type in the `CREATE` query written specific to Oracle DB, it is throwing an error.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Share the error its throwing

Comment: Is the manual really that hard to understand? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can't specify a maximum length for a BLOB.  Simply remove the `(102400)`.