# Creating or altering BLOB/CLOB column length - Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a varchar2 column and I want to store data bigger than 4k of length. So I created a new column BLOB. But, I saw that the length is also 4k by default.

How can I make it bigger than 4k? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No BLOB can store up to 4GB not 4KB.

Comment: Thanks! It probably was a misinterpretation of mine, because I was creating the column through DBeaver, and the IDE showed me length of 4000, then I assumed it was the same of varchar2 max size. Right after your answer, I tested it with a data bigger than 4k and it really worked.

Comment: 4GB was the limit till Oracle 10.2. Current maximum size is : (4 GB - 1) * `DB_BLOCK_SIZE` initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)

Comment: Just as an aside, if you are storing text, use a `CLOB` not a `BLOB`.  A `BLOB` is for storing binary information (pictures, movies, etc.).  A `CLOB` is for storing large amounts of text data.  If you store character data in a `BLOB` your applications will be responsible for doing things like character set conversion which is generally not something you want to be dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

DBeaver is probably misinterpreting `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_LENGTH` and showing incorrect information.  As others have pointed out, BLOBs and CLOBs can store many gigabytes of data.

For most columns, `DATA_LENGTH` shows important information about the maximum size of data.  But for BLOBs and CLOBs, `DATA_LENGTH` only indicates how much data could be stored *within the row*, which doesn't matter to users 99.99% of the time.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5687375/409172) for a more thorough explanation of what the exact number means.